# assets:precompile results in LoadError: cannot load such file -- sassc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-7

New Rails 7 app using `esbuild` with `tailwind`.

When I run `rake assets:precompile` I'm getting this error: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- sassc`

I removed the `sassc-rails` gem [due a SaasC syntax error](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails#how-do-i-avoid-sasscsyntaxerror-exceptions-on-existing-projects).

Here's the full output of precompiling locally...

```
rake assets:precompile
yarn install v1.22.15
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.06s.
yarn run v1.22.15
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds

  app/assets/builds/application.js      185.5kb
  app/assets/builds/application.js.map  301.0kb

✨  Done in 0.13s.
yarn install v1.22.15
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.06s.
yarn run v1.22.15
$ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css

Done in 155ms.
✨  Done in 0.52s.
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sassc

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And here's the output from Heroku...

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.22.17
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       success Saved lockfile.
       Done in 4.39s.
       yarn run v1.22.17
       $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds
       
         app/assets/builds/application.js      185.5kb
         app/assets/builds/application.js.map  301.0kb
       
       Done in 0.11s.
       yarn install v1.22.17
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       success Already up-to-date.
       Done in 0.13s.
       yarn run v1.22.17
       $ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css
       
       Done in 440ms.
       Done in 0.99s.
       rake aborted!
       LoadError: cannot load such file -- sassc
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/autoload/sassc.rb:2:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:42:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:27:in `new'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:27:in `instance'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:27:in `call'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `block in synchronize'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `synchronize'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `synchronize'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:19:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:363:in `run_task'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:335:in `loop'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:335:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `catch'
       /tmp/build_7c167d00/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block in create_worker'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Not sure what else to try here.

Comment: same problem here - ended up adding 'sass-rails' again in the meanwhile

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today and resolved it on the Heroku end by clearing the Heroku build cache [(instructions here)](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache)

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-builds

heroku builds:cache:purge -a example-app
```

Comment: Thank you! It also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and resolved by following.

- All .scss to .css in app/assets/stylesheets/*
  (If you have written `@import ...` in .scss files, fix to `*= require ...`
- `$ bundle clean`

In my case, I guess that because I had used bootstrap before tailwind, .scss files that about bootstrap had been remained in vendor/bundle.

Comment: I faced with same issue again when I installed other gem and not resolved by `$ bundle clean`.

So, I tried `$ rails tmp:clear`, the issue have been resolved.